# Не найден метод WindowsIdentity.Impersonate()

Tags: asp.net-core

Был проект ASP.NET Core 1.0. В нём прекрасно работал метод `WindowsIdentity.Impersonate()`. Затем проект пересоздали на ASP.NET Core 2.0, и этот метод стал недоступен. Как его подключить?

```
public class WebApiServiceInvoker
{
    private readonly HttpClientProvider _clientProvider;
    private readonly WindowsIdentity _identity;

    public WebApiServiceInvoker(HttpClientProvider httpClientProvider, WindowsIdentity currentIdentity)
    {
        this._clientProvider = httpClientProvider;
        this._identity = currentIdentity;
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Execute(string resource, string method, IDictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
        using (this._identity.Impersonate()) //метод не найден
        {
            var serializedParameters = SerializeParameters(method?.ToLowerInvariant(), parameters);

            return await PerformRequest(this._clientProvider.HttpClient, resource, method?.ToLowerInvariant(), serializedParameters);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Перегуглил весь инет, решения вопроса не нашёл, буду очень признателен за помощь.

Comment: Неужели никто не применял имперсонацию HTTP запросов?

Comment: На официальном сайте детально описана миграция до 2 версии: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x 
Надеюсь поможет... 
И еще: http://tech.trailmax.info/2017/07/user-impersonation-in-asp-net-core/